# Getting ordered keys from OrderDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdictionary

I saw some post to use [this Ordered Dictionary](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/ordereddictionary-subclassing-cocoa.html) solution in order to keep NSDictionary ordred.

It saves it in the same order that I get it from json object, but since I need to use the values for a UIPickerView, I wrote the following:

```
 OrderedDictionary *countryStates = [businessInfo objectForKey:@"allowedStates"];

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
        NSString *stateShort = [countryStates keyAtIndex:row ];
        return [countryStates objectForKey:stateShort];
}
```

However, I get:

```
[__NSCFDictionary keyAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

1. Why do I get it?
2. In what other way I can use the ordered dictionary for UIPickerView without ruining the order?

Comment: 1. Because `[businessInfo objectForKey:@"allowedStates"]` is only an `NSMutableDictionary` (as its class shows), not an `OrderedDictionary`. 2. I don't follow. You set the appropriate object as its property and don't let it go.

Comment: Thanks. But for UIPickerView I need to create 2 NSArray no?

Comment: I don't know. It depends on how you use it. Please show some more code+context.

Answer (score 2):

You get this error because the object associated to the `@"allowedStates"` in `businessInfo` is only a `NSDictionay`. You should use `OrderedDictionary`'s `+ (id)dictionaryWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict` method to create a new object and then manipulate it.

Comment: Can you please explain your answer how can I use dictionaryWithDictionary?

Comment: @Odelya You **call** it.

Comment: Like this : `OrderedDictionary *orderedCountryStates = [OrderedDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[businessInfo objectForKey:@"allowedStates"]];`

Comment: I tried your code, but actually this makes the order of the original NSDictionary become inorder

Comment: Then I suppose `OrderedDictionary` doesn't reimplement all the methods it should… Try `OrderedDictionary *orderedCountryStates = [OrderedDictionary dictionary]; [orderedCountryStates addEntriesFromDictionary:[businessInfo objectForKey:@"allowedStates"]];`